# Using the MIN() function with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, min

I have a little question. I am doing a Data Science SQL Course on Coursera and have the following task:

> Problem 7: Using INNER JOIN, find the minimum “Average Student Attendance” for community area where hardship is 96.

I solved the problem like this:

```
SELECT S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE, S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, C.HARDSHIP_INDEX
FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS as S
INNER JOIN CENSUS_DATA as C
ON C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
WHERE C.HARDSHIP_INDEX = 96
ORDER BY S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

However, originally I wanted to solve it elegant without `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.
The `MIN(S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE)` function doesn't work for me - I get an error:

```
An expression starting with "HARDSHIP_INDEX" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.. SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

**Is there a way the problem can be solved with MIN?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not use LIMIT and ORDER BY? it is a legitimate approach, unless you want to get ties (i.e. more then 1 row of same minimum)

Answer (score 0):

A way to use min is like so:

```
SELECT
    S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE
  , S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
  , C.HARDSHIP_INDEX
FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS AS S
INNER JOIN CENSUS_DATA AS C ON C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
WHERE C.HARDSHIP_INDEX = 96
AND S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE = (
    SELECT
        MIN( S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE )
    FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS AS S
    INNER JOIN CENSUS_DATA AS C ON C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
    WHERE C.HARDSHIP_INDEX = 96
)
```

Depending on the database you are using, if it supports common table expressions,  you could do this:

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT
        S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE
      , S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
      , C.HARDSHIP_INDEX
    FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS AS S
    INNER JOIN CENSUS_DATA AS C ON C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
    WHERE C.HARDSHIP_INDEX = 96
)
SELECT
    *
FROM cte
WHERE AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE = (
    SELECT
        MIN( AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE )
    FROM cte
)
```

If your version of MySQL supports window functions (v8 or later) then something like this may also work:

```
SELECT
    AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE
  , COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
  , HARDSHIP_INDEX
FROM (
    SELECT
        S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE
      , S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
      , C.HARDSHIP_INDEX
      , MIN( S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE ) OVER () AS min_att
    FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS AS S
    INNER JOIN CENSUS_DATA AS C ON C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
    WHERE C.HARDSHIP_INDEX = 96
) sq
WHERE AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE = min_att
```

Note `OVER()` i.e. nothing inside the over clause, is not allowed in all databases, it may need  something like `over(partition by C.HARDSHIP_INDEX)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is the right method to use.  However, you can use the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick if you *really* want to:

```
SELECT MAX(S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME ORDER BY S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE ASC), ',', 1),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(C.HARDSHIP_INDEX ORDER BY S.AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE ASC), ',', 1)
FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS S INNER JOIN
     CENSUS_DATA  C
     ON C.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER = S.COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER
WHERE C.HARDSHIP_INDEX = 96;
```